# Using $_GET in PHP with strings

Tags: php

Passing the value of 'false' into the $_GET Parameter. However, PHP does not seem to recognize this as a string since the following does not work:

```
$SINGLE = $_GET['SINGLE'];

if ($SINGLE == 'false'){
    echo 'HELLO';
}
```

I am guessing that I have to do some converting or casting, but I have not been successful.

Comment: Remove the quotes from 'false' unles you're passing a string. How're you setting `$_GET['SINGLE']`?

Comment: what's the URL u pass over? Maybe it's not written in caps

Comment: I think the question is a bit incomplete without including the URL. If `$_GET['SINGLE']` really does contain the string `'false'`, then you should see HELLO displayed. Everything from $_GET is going to be a string, so you shouldn't have to do any type conversion.

Comment: Like what @Don'tPanic said, could you please provide the link or an example of what you are trying to do so we can get a better understanding?

Comment: we have no idea where or how you're getting the array value's from. You're just assigning a variable to a GET array which far as I can tell, does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If your php file contains just the code example in your question, like this:

*yourfile.php*

```
<?php

$SINGLE = $_GET['SINGLE'];

if ($SINGLE == 'false'){
    echo 'HELLO';
}
```

You can get it to echo HELLO by accessing the file with this URL:

```
http://yourhost/pathto/yourfile.php?SINGLE=false
```

Keep in mind this is case sensitive. The case of the url parameter *must* match the case of the key in `$_GET`.

**You don't need to do any type conversion for this to work.**

PHP automatically populates the `$_GET` superglobal by parsing the query string of the HTTP request, and every scalar value in `$_GET` will be a string. It's possible for it to have some array structure with complex query strings, but inside the arrays everything will be a string. There seems to be some confusion because you used the string `'false'`, but there will never be a boolean in `$_GET` unless you explicitly put it there in your PHP code with `$_GET['SINGLE'] = false;`.

PHP does not do any automatic conversion of strings to booleans if they happen to contain `'true'` or `'false'`, and if you try to explicitly cast them they will both evaluate to `true`.

```
$example = (bool) 'false';
var_dump($example);   // bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

So issue number one is you will return an undefined index error that looks like this.

`Notice: Undefined index: SINGLE in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\test.php on line 2`

To resolve this you need to do the following block:

```
if(isset($_GET['SINGLE'])) {
    $SINGLE = $_GET['SINGLE'];
}
```

Reason for this is that PHP needs to verify that the `$_GET` essentially exists and well... is set. If there is no check code block, you will return `undefined` every single time.

Secondly, as people stated in the comments, you would not be putting `false` in quotes `true`/`false` are BOOLEANS. When you wrap them in quotes, it makes it a string. It's the same thing with numbers:

`1` is different from `'1'`. Once you wrap it in quotes, it is a string. So if your `$_GET`value is truly a BOOLEAN you would check it like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['SINGLE']) && $_GET['SINGLE'] == false) {
    $SINGLE = $_GET['SINGLE'];
} else {
    // other code here to execute if needed
}
```

Now if `$_GET` IS NOT a boolean and a string, you can check it like above and add an extra check as such:

```
if(isset($_GET['SINGLE']) && !empty($_GET['SINGLE'])) {
    $SINGLE = $_GET['SINGLE'];
} else {
    // other code here to execute if needed
}
```

I hope this helps you with what you are trying to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

tis better to make sure $_GET['SINGLE'] is exist or not at first:

```
if(isset($_GET['SINGLE'])) {
   $SINGLE = $_GET['SINGLE'];
    if ($SINGLE == 'false'){ // IF AS STRING
      echo 'HELLO STRING';
    }
    if ($SINGLE == false){ // IF AS BOOLEAN
      echo 'HELLO BOOLEAN';
    }
} else {
   // if not exist 
}
```